# How to explore Azure Reporting (SSRS) rendering extensions

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, azure, reporting

Is is possible to explore the supported rendering extensions for Azure Reporting? I want to supply the user with a list of supported extensions which he/she can choose from. I want that list to be generated, not hard coded (not in a config either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2012/08/25/get-sql-server-2012-ssrs-report-rendering-extensions-using-powershell/).

The solution is: Instantiate a new instance of the ReportViewer class, set processing mode to remote and call the ListRenderingExtensions method.

```
private RenderingExtension[] getSupportedRenderingExtensions()
{
    var reportViewer = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer();
    reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
    reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(_reportingAgent.ReportingServiceUrl);
    reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials("user", "password", "ReportingServiceUrl");

    return reportViewer.ServerReport.ListRenderingExtensions();
 }
```